# How do I change a View in a RecyclerView from MainActivity

Tags: android

I have some buttons in my `RecyclerView`, but when button(0) is long pressed, an `Intent` opens the gallary so the user can chose an image as a background for a   `RelativeLayout`. When an image has been choosen I want that button(0) to change its Alpha to indicate that an Image is choosen. How can I archive this?

**The chosen image is retrived in my MainActivity like this:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1 && data != null) {

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString(App.IMAGE_URI, data.getData().toString()).apply();
        Picasso.with(this).load(data.getData()).centerCrop().resize(width, height).into(target);
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("IMAGE", true).apply();

    }

}
```

**This intent code is in the adapter here:**

```
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        if (getAdapterPosition() == 0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a background image");
            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, GET_IMG_REQ);

        }
```

Comment: Why do you need listener? Why is this approach not suitable for you?

Comment: @skywall How would I know if the `intent.data != null` and therefor change the alpha of button(0) in my recyclerview?

Comment: You'll likely need the position of the clicked button in the list, store that into the intent, then you should be able to find that position back in the result, and update the view.

Comment: @cricket_007 How would I accses a view in a RecyclerView from my mainActivity?

Comment: Without seeing your code for the adapter, all I can suggest is that you have some list of object that is "bound" to your Adapter. You can easily access that list with `get(position)`, and with that object, you `setImageChosen()`, for example. Then, you simply `notify` the adapter that the data has been changed, the the view will update

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way is that creating a variable like `idClick` in your adapter, after that you can get the `idClick` through your activity contaning adapter.

**Adapter**

```
public class FakeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    List<View> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    List<View> footers = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final int TYPE_HEADER = 111;
    public static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 222;
    public static final int TYPE_ITEM = 333;

    private List<Item> items;
    private Activity context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public int idClick = -1;

    public FakeAdapter(List<Item> items, Activity context) {
        this.context = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        if (items == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException(
                    "items must not be null");
        }
        this.items = items;
    }

    public void clear() {
        if (items != null) {
            items.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                    from(parent.getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.view_item_fake,
                            parent,
                            false);
            return new QuestionHolder(itemView);
        } else {
            //create a new framelayout, or inflate from a resource
            FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(parent.getContext());
            //make sure it fills the space
            frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            return new HeaderFooterViewHolder(frameLayout);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //check what type of view our position is
        if (position < headers.size()) {
            View v = headers.get(position);
            //add our view to a header view and display it
            bindHeaderFooter((HeaderFooterViewHolder) holder, v);
        } else if (position >= headers.size() + items.size()) {
            View v = footers.get(position - items.size() - headers.size());
            //add oru view to a footer view and display it
            bindHeaderFooter((HeaderFooterViewHolder) holder, v);
        } else {
            //it's one of our items, display as required
            bindHolder((QuestionHolder) holder, position - headers.size());
        }
    }

    private void bindHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterViewHolder vh, View view) {
        //empty out our FrameLayout and replace with our header/footer
        vh.base.removeAllViews();
        vh.base.addView(view);
    }

    private void bindHolder(final QuestionHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Item item = getItem(position);
        if (item != null) {
            holder.button.setText(item.getTitle());
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getPathFromGallery())) {
            holder.button.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright));
        } else {
            holder.button.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        }

        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                idClick = position;
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                context.startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RecyclerListActivity.REUQUEST_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return headers.size() + items.size() + footers.size();
    }

    public Item getItem(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= items.size()) {
            return null;
        }
        return items.get(position);
    }

    public final static class QuestionHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.header_text)
        Button button;

        public QuestionHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    final static class HeaderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //@Bind(R.id.header_merchant)
        public TextView header;

        public HeaderHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            header = (TextView) itemView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        //check what type our position is, based on the assumption that the order is headers > items > footers
        if (position < headers.size()) {
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        } else if (position >= headers.size() + items.size()) {
            return TYPE_FOOTER;
        }
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    //add a header to the adapter
    public void addHeader(View header) {
        if (header != null && !headers.contains(header)) {
            headers.add(header);
            //animate
            notifyItemInserted(headers.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    //remove a header from the adapter
    public void removeHeader(View header) {
        if (header != null && headers.contains(header)) {
            //animate
            notifyItemRemoved(headers.indexOf(header));
            headers.remove(header);
            if (header.getParent() != null) {
                ((ViewGroup) header.getParent()).removeView(header);
            }
        }
    }

    //add a footer to the adapter
    public void addFooter(View footer) {
        if (footer != null && !footers.contains(footer)) {
            footers.add(footer);
            //animate
            notifyItemInserted(headers.size() + items.size() + footers.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    //remove a footer from the adapter
    public void removeFooter(View footer) {
        if (footer != null && footers.contains(footer)) {
            //animate
            notifyItemRemoved(headers.size() + items.size() + footers.indexOf(footer));
            footers.remove(footer);
            if (footer.getParent() != null) {
                ((ViewGroup) footer.getParent()).removeView(footer);
            }
        }
    }

    //our header/footer RecyclerView.ViewHolder is just a FrameLayout
    public static class HeaderFooterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        FrameLayout base;

        public HeaderFooterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.base = (FrameLayout) itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

**Item**

```
public class Item {

    private String title;
    private String pathFromGallery;

    public Item(String title, String pathFromGallery) {
        this.title = title;
        this.pathFromGallery = pathFromGallery;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPathFromGallery() {
        return pathFromGallery;
    }

    public void setPathFromGallery(String pathFromGallery) {
        this.pathFromGallery = pathFromGallery;
    }
}`
```

Activity

```
public class RecyclerListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.srl)
    SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    FakeAdapter adapter;
    List<Item> lsItem;
    public static int REUQUEST_LOAD_IMAGE = 1111;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setAdapter();
    }


    private void setAdapter() {
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            }
        });
        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new FakeAdapter(getLsItem(), this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    private List<Item> getLsItem() {
        lsItem = new ArrayList<>();
        lsItem.add(new Item("Button 1", ""));
        lsItem.add(new Item("Button 2", ""));
        lsItem.add(new Item("Button 3", ""));
        lsItem.add(new Item("Button 4", ""));

        return lsItem;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == REUQUEST_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();


                updateAdapter(imgDecodableString);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    private void updateAdapter(String path) {
        if(adapter.idClick != -1) {
            lsItem.get(adapter.idClick).setPathFromGallery(path);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

`view_item_fake.xml` has only a button. Is it the answer you want because I don't see you adapter. I have just modified my codes base on my old project (the naming maybe you confused), in `FakeAdapter` you just need to see method `bindHolder`.

Comment: This dosn't give any sense. I have edited my question. Read it again thx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the main problem is to tell the adapter the image is available and make button_0 contained in `RecyclerView` item, alpha change.

There is `RecyclerView.Adapter's` method `notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)`. If it's called, particular item is re-binded (`onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position, List<Object> payload)` is called). In payload you can specify additional to item "refreshment". Let's use it in your scenario:

Adapter's implementation:

```
// Helper class to indicate that we should decrease provided item's button alpha
public class DecreaseAlpha { }

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
    if (!payloads.isEmpty() && payloads.get(0) instanceof DecreaseAlpha) {
        holder.your_button.setAlpha(0.5f);
    } else {
        // make sure to call classic version of onBindViewHolder when payload is not available
        onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    }

}
```

Usage in Activity class:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1 && data != null) {
        ...
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(position_of_item_with_button_0, new DecreaseAlpha());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes if the user have chosen an image from the gallary, the button at index 0 shall go from its default alpha(0.5f) to alpha(1). Just as an simple visual indicator. I will try this out later.